# How to connect to an attached signal from C++?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, signals-slots, qt-signals

I want to connect to an object's `Component.onCompleted` signal from C++. What syntax should I use?

Comment: How are you creating the component? From C++ or QML?

Comment: I think that doesn't make sense. When you create QML tree with, for example,  `QQmlApplicationEngine::load()` the `Component.onCompleted` will be executed before you connect to the signal. Anyway - you can create some proxy signal for you object called from `Component.onCompleted` and so connect to this signal from C++.

Comment: Make the slot object accessible to QML via setContextProperty() and call the slot directly from the Component.onCompleted handler

Answer (score 0):

So you can use this code to get access to Component.completed and Component.destruction signals:

```
QObject* attached_component = qmlAttachedPropertiesObject<QQmlComponent>(qml_component);
QObject::connect(attached_component, SIGNAL(destruction()), this, SLOT(onDestruction()));
QObject::connect(attached_component, SIGNAL(completed()), this, SLOT(onCompleted()));
```

qml_component is your QML component pointer, 'this' is object that has onDestruction and onCompleted slots.
Maybe it's a hack but now it works(QT 5.8 VS2013)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to call a C++ funtion from QML:

```
Component.onCompleted:Qml_utils.connect_qmlobject(this)
```

C++ code

```
Q_INVOKABLE void qml_utils::connect_qmlobject(QObject*obj) {
  //do something with QML QObject:
  connect(obj, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)),
          this,SLOT(disconnect_qmlobject(QObject*)));
}
```